# C# Using Regex to find words, any tips?

Tags: c#

So i am studying programming in university and i have a task for which i need to use especially Regex.

So basically, i need to make program, which copies the text from first file until it meets first non-copied word from second file or it reaches the end of the file and when it finds that non-copied word (or reaches the end of the file), then it copies text from second file until it meets first non-copied word from first file or it reaches the end of the file, reapeat till both files end. Lower and Upper characters don't matter.

For example:

File1: You are very beautiful, can you give me your number?

File2: Beautiful is Beyonce, not me.

Result: You are very Beautiful is Beyonce, not me. beautiful, can you give me your number?

Yes, i know, it is a confused result, but i need to make, so do you have any ideas or tips, how i could make this program ?

Comment: You may want to read https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285 or a similar tutorial. :-)

Comment: You can match words by using the word boundary character  \b.

Comment: You could start by making an attempt...

Comment: Ignoring case differences is possible via the i flag. E.g. `/aBc/i`.

Comment: Also, there are great online tools that help you write / test regular expressions. For example this one: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, get yourself a Regex designer that follows .Net Regex rules.

I use: https://rad-software-regular-expression-designer.software.informer.com/

This is how you find words:
\b\w+\b
"A word boundary followed by at least 1 word char followed by a closing boundary", ensure you use the case insensitive RegexOption

Then, loop through both string using a case insensitive comparison to find matching words.

Once done, store the first word in a variable.

Now, create another Regex, it's match string is a "positive lookahead zero width assertion) around the first matching word. Don't forget the case insensitive switch.
If you match the word, the word gets replaced, instead we use "lookaround", which just return a zero width location and you get two "beautiful"s in the result

Use Regex's Instance method "Replace(left, right)"

Now, I've also thrown the code together but you're *supposed* to be doing this yourself.

```
// So I've hidden the code in this pastebin:

https://pastebin.com/fBAu1zBY

// Only go there is you've not managed to figure this out for yourself!
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)